# How to cite lecture notes in IEEE standard

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to cite a lecture note using the IEEE citation standard (\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran})

Here's my entry:

```
@misc{Lecture,
    author = {Timm-Giel, Andreas and Nga Tran, Phuong},
    institution = {Institute of Communication Networks at the Technical University Hamburg},
    howpublished = {Lecture Notes},
    year = {WS 2013/2014},
    title = {Communication Networks {I}},
}
```

The institution does not get listet, which is kinda stupid, since crucial.

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Comment: If this is the bibliography style you are required to use, then you should not change it. If the institution does not appear, it's because it should not. Although, it could be done by modifying the style, or by changing the type of key for the institution (putting it in `howpublished`, for example), but it is not recommended.

Comment: ok. Thx for your reply!